# Mulitmap or sorted vector in a parallel program

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, parallel-processing, multimap

I have a program that I must parallelize it. it may contain a large number of data. These data can be identified by an id and more data can have the same id. Each thread of my program recovers all data with a certain id and work on it.

My question is for a parallel program the best solution is to use a multimap or vector sorted by the id of the data?

Thank you.

Comment: How much data are we talking about? What kind of data and what kind of processing? Is it really a requirement that one thread processes the data for one particular ID, or are you looking for a general load-balancing strategy, and the IDs doen't necessarily have anything to do with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abstract the data-type and implement general solution. Then replace the two data-type and see which one performs better.

Comment: I've replace the vector by a multimap and performance is better but my program is , at the moment, sequential , but i wondered if the multimap is better in multithreading program for cache affinity because the vector is contiguous in memory whereas multimap isn't contiguous.

Comment: Best way to find out is to try it, so go ahead and see which one actually performs better. Then you can try to rationalize the behavior. Also note the extra size of multimap versus a concise vector. Not sure if this will be a problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size of the data. For instance, if you have data `A` `B` `C` and `D` with size 2, 10, 20, 30, and running with 4 threads, you will have load balancing problems. Thread A will do less work than the remaining. Unfortunately, sorting the data will not help you.

It might be better to just store the data in a stack (for example) and make the threads take work from the stack to be done, independently of the id. However, you have to synchronized the stack.

If you know beforehand the sizes that each id data contains, you can group them into blocks compose of the data ids. This blocks would have approximately the same size.

Then you could make a map `<K,V>` where the `V` would be the blocks and `K` the id of the thread that will compute those blocks.

Answer (score 0):

unordered_map may be a good solution. As it is implemented as a hash, same id's will end up in same buckets. 
Also, hash tables are good when dealing with large data sets, as they provide a mechanism to group data into buckets that can be processed separately.